# settransform() method in Android

Tags: android, andengine

In j2me there is a method called `settransform()`  sameway in  android what method do i need to use to get a miror image of sprite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `Sprite.setFlippedHorizontal(boolean pFlippedHorizontal)` and `Sprite.setFlippedVertical(boolean pFlippedVertical)`